# Checking for feature / class on OS version?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am developing an application that I want to run on both iOS4 and iOS5 but for users of iOS5 I want to use an iOS5 feature as part of the interface (iOS4 users will get something less exciting). My question is what is the procedure for checking the availability of a particular OS on a device. My understanding is that I don't check the OS version but rather the availability of a particular class, can anyone help me out of the best way to do this ...

Comment: This question is already on Google! :rolleyes:

Comment: @Bo A, much appreciated, thank you for the link.

Answer (score 4):

Isn't iOS 5 under NDA?

Anyway, to check if a feature exists then try this:

```
if (NSClassFromString(@"UIStepper")) {
    //enter code here
} else {
    //enter code here
}
```

Customise to your needs.

*EDIT: iOS 5 is now released so I can now add "UIStepper" to my code.*

Comment: +1 for the NDA reminder, I have removed anything offending. I don't think I need worry about the words (or future release of) iOS5 as its mentioned an Apples main public page.

Comment: @fuzzygoat - It's not that it's offending or anything - it's just protected under NDA.   You are right in saying that mentioning the word(s) "iOS 5" should not be problem.  Also, how are you getting on with `NSClassFromString`?

Comment: UIStepper is an interesting example because that's exactly what causes my app to crash on my iOS 4.2.1 device, but i'm finding it only crashes saying it can't set a value to the component. The component itself shows up fine. So I've ended up doing: if (![myStepper respondsToSelector:@selector(setValue:)]) myStepper.hidden=true;

Answer (score 2):

```
Class stepperClass = NSClassFromString(@"UIStepper");
if (stepperClass) {
    // class is available, use it
} else {
    // class not available, don't use it or use something else
}
```

Answer (score 2):

iOS5 is under NDA so i wouldnt mention any new classes that may or may not exist. However the following code should do what you want. It's lifted from the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Using/using.html).

```
if ([UINewClass class]) {
    // Create an instance of the class and use it.

} else {
    // Alternate code path to follow when the
    // class is not available.

}
```

This uses Weak Linking and therefore requires that the new class (UINewClass) to be in the SDK you are using to compile. It is a relatively new feature introduced in iOS 4.2 and might not be supported by all the frameworks. A workaround is to use the older style (from the same link as above):

```
Class cls = NSClassFromString (@"UINewClass");
if (cls) {
    // Create an instance of the class and use it.
} else {
    // Alternate code path to follow when the
    // class is not available.
}
```

Comment: `[UISomeNewClass class]` won’t work when running on iOS < 3.1 because weak linking isn’t supported, though. If you really need to support iOS versions that old, you’ll need to use `NSStringFromClass()`.

Comment: @gcbrueckmann: I didnt know that, thanks. Although the OP states he only wants to support 4 and 5.

Comment: @brain my bad, I copy/pasted it into Xcode, saw and error and made a wrong assumption. It would not compile on iOS SDK older than 5.0, but it would work on iOS >= 3.1 as gcbrueckmann pointed out. Deleted my previous comment to not cause confusion.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to get the UIStepper to gracefully degrade in 4.x, you cannot only use

```
if( NSClassFromString(@"UIStepper") )
```

Instead, you must also check for a UIStepper-specific selector having a response.  As Harry Wood suggested in the comment under Bo A, a good way to do it is:

```
if( NSClassFromString(@"UIStepper") && [theStepper respondsToSelector:@selector(setValue:)] )
```

This solved the issue of my app crashing under iOS 4.x.

Harry Wood helped me solve the issue I was seeing, and I would like him to get the credit.